# ArcMap 10; Syntax for Minimum operator in raster calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster-calculator

I want to linear stretch my raster grid formate having column/rows 3128, 3503 with 30 meter resolution by using the following syntax in raster calculator of arcmap 10.1.

```
("raster" - FocalStatistics("raster", NbrRectangle, 30, 30, "Minimum") / 
(FocalStatistics("raster", NbrRectangle, 30, 30, "Maximum") - 
FocalStatistics("raster", NbrRectangle, 30, 30, "Minimum"))
```

But this gives me the error while executing. 
I have also tried the simple equation but did not work.

```
("raster" - min("raster")) * 1.0 / (max("raster") - min("raster")) + 0.0
```

Error displayed:

> 000539 : Error message from Python.
>   ArcGIS 10.1 Locate topic
>   Description
>   The calculation used by the Calculate Field or Calculate Value tool is
>   invalid. This error message provided will list the specific Python
>   error.
>   Solution
>   This error code covers a number of Python errors:
>   Example error 1: exceptions.TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects.The 
>   above is a Python-specific error. The calculation is attempting to add
>   or concatenate a string and a number.
>   Example error 2: Invalid field shape@distance
>   The above is an error using the geometry object. The distance method
>   is not a valid method of the geometry object.For specific Python
>   issues, consult the external Python help for more information, or
>   consult the Calculate Field or Calculate Value help for more
>   information on these tools.

What is the right syntax.

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 2):

The expression of the rectangle is incorrect, your neighbourhood should be specified like this:

```
FocalStatistics("raster",NbrRectangle(30,30),"MINIMUM")
```

As the NbrRectangle is an object... to specify your first calculation use:

```
("raster" - FocalStatistics("raster",NbrRectangle(30,30),"MINIMUM"))  
/ ((FocalStatistics("raster",NbrRectangle(30,30),"MAXIMUM")) 
- (FocalStatistics("raster",NbrRectangle(30,30),"MINIMUM")))
```

The 'simple' equation is anything but... minimum and maximum can only be obtained when statistics have been built, if they are not you will receive an error saying `'value unobtainable'` or something along those lines. Using the whole raster min and max:

```
Con(IsNull("raster"),-9999,("raster"
/ (float(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("raster","MAXIMUM").getOutput(0)) 
- float(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("raster","MINIMUM").getOutput(0))) * 100))
```

Comment: @MichaelMS. I have already tried the same syntax you mentioned first but received the error while executing. Please see I have edited my syntax in main post. I want to rescale it into 0-1 range. I don't get your second option or not explained well to understand. Is this syntax for use in python or? Add you had missed some expression in numerator part.

Comment: I've broken them up into three lines to make it easier to read. In order to get a numeric minimum and maximum you need to use getOutput(0), which is a string, and then use float to make it a floating point number. Both of these worked for me with no error messages.

Comment: @MichaelMS. Your first syntax by using raster calculator works for me successfully. I had missed one bracket in it. I am a new to use python this is why I might be panic to ask such a basic questions. As my understanding, you did not subtract the minimum value from the main raster before division (in numerator part) as I need to subtract first from the main raster and then divide it with dynamic range. Thanks anyway